# Multi-hop linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 servers.

SQL Server 2008 (Server A)
SQL Server 2008 (Server B)
Oracle Server (Server C)

Server A has a linked server set up to Server B and Server B has a linked server set up to Server C.

Can I create a Linked server from Server A to Server C via Server B?

If not, how can I reference the tables in Server C from Server A?

EDIT:

Ok, so I guess my real question is what is the syntax needed to query on Server C from Server A?

Comment: Not really on topic; you would get better answers from DBAs or Server Admins than Developers.

Answer (score 3):

To answer you question. Can I create a Linked server from Server A to Server C via Server B?
Yes you can by creating a view of what you want from Server C on a Server B database then accessing it via linked server on Server A.

But my question for you why cant you just link Server A to Server C?

Comment: Sigh...DBA's on a power trip.